# Unable to select PHP Composer in Artifactory Package View

Tags: composer-php, artifactory

For some reason I am unable to select PHP Composer from the drop down menu on the package view page in our Artifactory portal (the option is greyed out). We do have both private and public composer repositories and a number of composer packages in Artifacts. We have the same for NPM packages and yet we are able to select NPM from the list in package view.

Searching for this issue and any resolution has yielded nothing so I'm asking here :)

Thanks,
Felicity

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the newly added [Package Viewer UI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Viewing+Packages).
It does not yet support PHP.

It supports Docker starting version 5.10 and NPM starting 6.4.0.
Most probably you are unable to select NPM as you are running a version between 5.10 and 6.4.

Comment: Ha! Thank you! :) :) I don't know how on earth I couldn't find that wiki page before!